# Saving and reading ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, save

Saving method (save list is an Arraylist):

```
public static void saveList(){
    editor.putString("list", Calculate.saveList.toString());
}
```

My reading method (probably where my problem is):

```
public static void readList(){
    String arrayString= prefs.getString("list", null);
    Calculate.saveList = (ArrayList<String>) Arrays.asList(arrayString.split(","));
}
```

Logcat error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tsury.icalorie/com.tsury.icalorie.SavedActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] java.lang.String.split(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

I need to save that ArrayList and of course reading it later.

Comment: Are you making sure to call `.apply()` or `.commit()` on your `editor` object when saving?

Comment: Did so, now im getting this error-

                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tsury.icalorie/com.tsury.icalorie.SavedActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

you can convert your array list to json string and save it as string 
and read that json string and convert it to your object.

you can use Gson library to do that.

do this steps:

1- add this dependancy in your Gradle file

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
```

make a class that keep your ArrayList

```
class MyList{
   @SerializedName("myStrings")
   public ArrayList<String> myStrings;
}
```

create an instance of MyList class and add your values in myStrings .

```
MyList myListInstance=new MyList(); 
myList.myStrings.add("Peter");
myList.myStrings.add("John");
myList.myStrings.add("Faraz");
```

then conver your MyList object to Json using this line:

```
String json=new Gson().toJson(myListInstance)
```

and save this json String in sharedPreferences

when you want to load your data read your json string from sharedPreferences and then convert it to your object using this line

```
MyList myList = new Gson().fromJson(json, MyList.class);
```

Comment: Is there any example for doing so?

Comment: How should I do that: "create an instance of MyList class and add string your values in myString."?